# XCode localization and SVN problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, svn, localization

I added three localization to my project in XCode but I can commit to SVN only default language 'English' but another two I can't. Next to 'Localizable.strings(SomeLanguage)' I have only 'A' but can't add it to repo. What am I missing here? First time work with localization, XCode 4...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An 'A' next to the filename when you run `svn stat` means that the file has already been added. In order to make that change in the repository, you need to commit the change:

`svn commit -m "Adding localizations for Hungarian and Urdu."`

Comment: No, when I try to commit that file (with 'A') I got something like this: svn: commit failed (details bellow): /users/user/documents/projects...de.lproj is not under version control and is not part of the commit, yet its child 'users/user/...de.lproj/Localizable.strings is part of the commit.

Comment: Oops, sorry your solution from terminal works fine. Problem is solved but I still don't understand what occurs error from above.

Comment: Thanx for that. I had the same problem. My feeling is that integration os SVN in Xcode is vary basic and limited. I had several issues where I had to use the terminal.

Comment: @NobleK, I don't think that the svn support in Xcode was ever meant to replace the command line. Xcode's svn integration simplifies routine tasks like checking in files or comparing two versions of a file because you can do them within the IDE. For less common or more complicated operations, you still need to use the command line or a dedicated svn client such as [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/).

Comment: I agree. However, I use also Eclipse with the Subclipse plugin and rarely ever have to use the command line after the project has been set up.